# How to download files from a ftp server when certain file exists

Tags: apache-camel, sftp

I need to create a route in Camel in Spring DSL that waits for a certain file (done_*.ctl) to exists on a SFTP and then download all other files by a defined pattern (*.gz).

I tried using pollEnrich which did not work.

```
<route id="sftpDownloadCSVFiles">
  <from uri="{{sftp-done-fromUri}}"/>
  <log message="#### Found the signal file: '${header[CamelFileNameOnly]}'"/>

  get all files from sftp://{{sftp-inbound-fromUri}}

  <log message="All files downloaded."/>
</route>
```

I would like to download all *.gz files to the local disk and remove the done file.

Comment: You will need a custom [processStrategy](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-ftp/src/main/docs/sftp-component.adoc) which implements `GenericFileProcessStrategy`. Here in `prepareOnStartup` or `begin` you could check for the existence of `done_ctl`. In case of an absence you can either throw an exception or in case of `begin` you can simply return false. I'm not sure if this is a lockfile in general, if so, you should do the whole handling of it inside this strategy

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Took the GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy and modified to my use case.

Comment: @RadovanBičiště Share the Karma. Why not post the solution as an answer, so that it helps someone in the future :)